# Deploying SSIS package with some csv files

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS BIDS 2008 R2. In my solution I have a Parent.dtsx package and there are a few child packages that the Parent package calls. The thing is that some of the Data Flow tasks in my packages (child or Parent) use some csv files that are kept in a folder hierarchy of the packages. 
Now I want to distribute my package so I have to deploy it. I have the following quesions -

1. How to make the my csv files part of the deployment.
2. All my File Connection Managers have absolute paths. How do I convert them to relative paths? Because this will be an important concern when other consumers try to run the package.
3. One of the OLE DB connection strings needs to be dynamic. I mean it has to be supplied at runtime when someone will try to run the package using dtexec.

Any help/suggestions/link to resources is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Have a look at Package Configurations under the SSIS menu. You can create an XML config file that can control your connection strings (including connection manager file paths)

Comment: Sure I'd take a look at that. What about deploying with my csv files contained in the the deployment package? Any idea about that one? Thanks for your response though !

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How to make the my csv files part of the deployment.

In the Solution Explorer you'll see there's a folder labelled "Miscellaneous". To add a file to here you need to go to the uppermost node and: **Right-click > Add > Existing Item...**

[image: Add existing item to SSIS package]

> 1. All my File Connection Managers have absolute paths. How do I convert them to relative paths? Because this will be an important concern when other consumers try to run the package.
> 2. One of the OLE DB connection strings needs to be dynamic. I mean it has to be supplied at runtime when someone will try to run the package using dtexec.

Both of these problems can be resolved by adding a configuration file to your SSIS package.

Open a SSIS package and you'll find the option on the file menu under: **SSIS > Package Configurations**

You'll be able to modify almost any property of your objects within the package.